# Unable to post authorization header in python requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I've been trying to post a payload to an endpoint, the endpoint requires bearer token.
using the python requests, I'm trying to post the bearer token in the header as

```
from requests import Session

http= Session()

accessToken = getToken(url=uri,data=payload)

authorization_header_string = 'bearer ' + accessToken

requestHeaders = {"Content-type": "text/plain", "Authorization":authorization_header_string}
         

headerData={"content-type":"text/plain","authorization":requestHeaders}

resp= http.post(url=uri,data=payload,headers=headerData)
```

but all I get is 401 error, while if I use the same token in postman it works fine.
I'm using requestbin to check wherein the authorization shows up only sometimes in the header.

Comment: Can you show the actual code (naturally without the actual token or URI), just so we can be sure about the format of your Authorization header?

Comment: Try using: `"Bearer " + accessToken`; only field names are case insensitive for HTTP headers; values may or may not be case sensitive.

Comment: Updated the code now

Comment: Tried with "Bearer " + accessToken it still didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```py
token = "your token"

headerData={"content-type": "text/plain", "authorization": "Bearer " + token}
```

Comment: Yes I have used the same format, the way i represented here was wrong, sorry